# after upgrading to rails 5.1.7 have an error ArgumentError: invalid argument: nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, scope

after upgrading to rails 5.1.7 have an error ArgumentError: invalid argument: nil.

tests:

```
describe 'default_for scope' do
    it 'joins intel_tags' do
      scope = IntelTagging.default_for('something')
      expect(scope.joins_values).to include(:intel_tag)
    end

    it 'uses IntelTag.default_for' do
      expect(IntelTag).to receive(:default_for).with('something')
      IntelTagging.default_for('something')
    end
  end
```

models:

```
class IntelTagging < ApplicationRecord
...
belongs_to :intel_tag, inverse_of: :intel_taggings, optional: true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :intel_tag

validates_presence_of :intel_tag

scope :default_for, ->(type) {
    joins(:intel_tag).merge(IntelTag.default_for(type))
  }

  scope :key, ->(key) { joins(:intel_tag).merge(IntelTag.key(key)) }
...
end
```

```
class IntelTag < ApplicationRecord
...
has_many :intel_taggings, inverse_of: :intel_tag, dependent: :destroy

scope :default_for, ->(string) { where(arel_table[:default_for].matches("%#{string}%")) }
...
end
```

I found that in rails 5 it a bit changed -> Raise `ArgumentError` when passing `nil` or `false` to `Relation#merge`.
These are not valid values to merge in a relation so it should warn the users early.

I did the following which quite ugly:

```
scope :default_for, ->(type) {
    joins_intel_tag = joins(:intel_tag)
    joins_intel_tag.merge(IntelTag.default_for(type)) if joins_intel_tag.present?
  }
```

but still have an error

```
 (IntelTag(id: integer, managed: boolean, default_for: text, unmanaged_name: string, name_en: string, name_fr: string, name_it: string, name_de: string, deleted_at: datetime, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, key: string) (class)).default_for("something")
           expected: 1 time with arguments: ("something")
           received: 0 times
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently did the following to make test pass but still investigating & searching for the better solution:

```
scope :default_for, ->(type) {
    joins(:intel_tag).merge(IntelTag.default_for(type)) unless IntelTag.default_for(type).nil?
  }

  scope :key, ->(key) {
    IntelTag.key(key).nil? ? joins(:intel_tag) : joins(:intel_tag).merge(IntelTag.key(key))
  }
```